# Flutter dialog: how to make scaffold wrap its content?

Tags: flutter, dialog, scaffold

```
showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (BuildContext context) => Dialog(
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text('My Title')),
          body: Text('Hello World');
        ),
      ),
    );
```

The dialog is too big (almost 90% of screen size). Without Scalffold, its size is wrapping content. Can the scalffold be constrained to wrap its content?

Comment: `Scaffold` official [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html) say: "The scaffold will expand to fill the available space. That usually means that it will occupy its entire window or device screen."

Comment: For web, all element sizing is configurable using css. Flutter adopts a different way, making widgets not configurable. :)

Comment: the question is why would you want a scaffold in a dialog at all?

Comment: Need a drawer to open a query form in a dialog.

Comment: All flutter widgets should have attribute width/height: match_parent/match_child.